# return the years for which the values are NA for specific countries in r

Tags: r

I'm new to R and couldn't find a solution to this.
I have a data set with Country Codes, Values, and Years(Panel Data)
The 'Value' column has many NAs. 
I would like to, for each country, get a list of years for which the values are NA. 
Would this be possible using the dplyr function? This is a snapshot of my data set
[Country codes, Years and Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy31H.png)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Point noted. Thanks.

Comment: Please post data in the post as text, preferably using `dput`, not as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the test case:

```
df <- read.table(text="Country  Year Value
UKR            2006  NA
UKR           2007  NA
UKR           2008  2000
ARE           2006   NA
ARE           2007   NA", header=TRUE)
```

> for each country, get a list of years for which the values are NA

```
lapply(split(df, df["Country"]), function(x) x$Year[is.na(x$Value)])
# or equivalent but more readable
with(subset(df, is.na(Value)), split(Year, Country))
```

Output:

```
$ARE
[1] 2006 2007

$UKR
[1] 2006 2007
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: That is what I need, but the lapply package isn't getting installed on my R. I will look into this and get back to you.

Comment: There is no separate package for lapply, its in base r

Comment: The code worked perfectly. Exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
DAT = read.table(text="Country.Code  Year  Value
UKR            2006  NA
UKR           2007  NA
UKR           2008  2000
ARE           2006   NA
ARE           2007   NA",
header=TRUE)

DAT[is.na(DAT$Value), 1:2]
  Country.Code Year
1          UKR 2006
2          UKR 2007
4          ARE 2006
5          ARE 2007
```

## Addition

To get all years for one country in a single line, you could use

```
temp = DAT[is.na(DAT$Value), 1:2]
aggregate(temp$Year, list(temp$Country.Code), paste, collapse=",")
  Group.1         x
1     ARE 2006,2007
2     UKR 2006,2007
```

Comment: Thank You!this worked perfectly! Is there anyway to have the country code only once and the years where its values are NA in the other column?

Comment: adding to answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the which function:

**df[is.na(which(df$value)),]**

Comment: This works. Thanks!